# Flutter save array into SharedPreferences

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have been reading trough various posts on how to store arrays at SharedPrefs, as I need to avoid asking the user for permissions on my project.

There are ways to convert it to another kind of value that can be stored, such as setting SetHash, but i cant figure out how to make it work, these are the vars that I need to get into sharedprefs. *choicemade, randomarray*:

¿what tweaks do I need to do to make the viable for SharedPref saving?

```
choicemade = {
      for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++,)
        '$i': {
          "choice": "no",
        }


for (int i = 0;;) {
          distinctIds.add(rand.nextInt(50) + 1);
          random_array = distinctIds.toSet().toList();
          if (random_array.length < 50) {
            continue;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
```

Comment: do you want to store it as Map?

Comment: I'm open to convert it to string for saving and then iterate to split it when load needed, anything but disk storage

Comment: You can use pref.setStringList(key, value)